# Select first row in a group by, with several columns defining the group

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

Here is a dummy table to describe what I am trying to do:

```
ID_1      | ID_2     | ID_3       | Day   | Energy_Costs  |
----------+----------+------------+-------+---------------+
State_1   | County_1 | Building_1 |  1    | 48.8          |
State_1   | County_1 | Building_1 |  2    | 31.3          |
State_1   | County_1 | Building_2 |  1    | 20.5          |
State_1   | County_2 | Building_1 |  1    |  1.9          |
State_2   | County_1 | Building_1 |  1    |  6.6          |
State_2   | County_2 | Building_2 |  1    | 38.2          |
State_2   | County_2 | Building_2 |  2    | 12.0          |
```

In the table above, a unique record (a Building in this case), requires 3 columns (ID_1, ID_2, ID_3). I would like to return a table with the first row of a given day for a building.

Here's how the query looks in my head:

```
SELECT FIRST(ID_1), FIRST(ID_2), FIRST(ID_3), FIRST(Energy_Costs), FIRST(DAY)
FROM buildings_db
GROUP BY ID_1, ID_2, ID_3
ORDER BY DAY
```

This would return:

```
ID_1      | ID_2     | ID_3       | Day   | Energy_Costs  |
----------+----------+------------+-------+---------------+
State_1   | County_1 | Building_1 |  1    | 48.8          |
State_1   | County_1 | Building_2 |  1    | 20.5          |
State_1   | County_2 | Building_1 |  1    |  1.9          |
State_2   | County_1 | Building_1 |  1    |  6.6          |
State_2   | County_2 | Building_1 |  1    | 38.2          |
```

I've seen other questions asking something similar but they typically don't have multiple columns defining a group. I'm very new to SQL so translating them to my example is proving unsuccessful; if any of you can provide an explanation for why your solution works that would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DISTINCT ON ()`. It works for any number of columns to define a group:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (ID_1, ID_2, ID_3)
       ID_1, ID_2, ID_3, DAY, Energy_Costs
FROM   buildings_db
ORDER  BY ID_1, ID_2, ID_3, DAY, Energy_Costs;
```

This returns the first row for each distinct combination of `(ID_1, ID_2, ID_3)`, first being defined by additional `ORDER BY` expressions.

To get ...

> the first row of a given day for a building:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (ID_1, ID_2, ID_3)
       ID_1, ID_2, ID_3, DAY, Energy_Costs
FROM   buildings_db
WHERE  DAY = 1  -- given day
ORDER  BY ID_1, ID_2, ID_3, Energy_Costs
```

Detailed explanation:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

Comment: Erwin,

Your response is extremely helpful! You've correctly answered the question, but I'm realizing I didn't create an accurate enough representation. One more flavor: instead of "Day" my data is time series. I want to return the earliest instance of time, which I cannot reliably state as one. Is there a dynamic way of doing what you did in your example? 

Something like: "Where Day = minimum(Day)"

Comment: @MattM: If you realize you have another, different question, just start a new question (with clear details). Comments are not the place.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a subquery and `JOIN` for this

```
select b.ID_1, b.ID_2, b.ID_3, b.Energy_Costs, b.DAY
from buildings_db b
join
(
  select ID_1, ID_2, ID_3, min(day) min_day
  from buildings_db 
  group by ID_1, ID_2, ID_3
) t on b.id_1 = t.id_1 and
       b.id_2 = t.id_2 and
       b.id_2 = t.id_2 and
       b.day = t.min_day
```